# PHP Multiple Prepared Statements

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I would like to execute two statements and print the results within a while loop. Each statement will select data from two different tables.

I'm not sure the best way to approach this.

My code so far is as follows;

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'db');

if ($conn->connect_errno > 0) {
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $conn->connect_error . ']');
} 

$curDate = date("Y-m-d");

//first stmt
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT start, status FROM log WHERE start >= ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $curDate);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($start, $status);
$stmt->close();

//second stmt
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT time FROM params");
$stmt->bind_result($time);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();


/* fetch values and echo for testing */
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $start;
    echo $status;
    echo $time;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Any reason you can't fetch them in one query?

Comment: I assume there must be a relation between the two queries otherwise it wouldn't matter if you looped through them in the same loop. Couldnt you just join the two tables together and select the columns you need in one query like Styphon said?

Comment: @Styphon I'm not really sure how to do that :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, there is **nothing** special in running two or dozen prepared statements - you just have run them one by one. Thus there is no "best way" at all.

In your particular case the best way is to get rid of prepared statements:

```
$time = $conn->query("SELECT time FROM params")->fetch_object()->time;

$res = $conn->query("SELECT start, status FROM log WHERE start >= CURDATE()");
while($row = $res->fetch_object())
{
    echo $row->start;
    echo $row->status;
    echo $time;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll give it a go now! Where do I include the execute() and close() statements?